# Keep Re-running Unit Test until getting `Failed`

Tags: unit-testing, rust, rust-cargo

I am having an inconsistent output when running a unit test. Most of the times the unit test passes without any issue, it's rare to have it failed.

Is there any `cargo test` parameter that might help to keep re-running the unit test until an error is encountered?

Comment: Why not put it in a shell script and loop?

Comment: @thebusybee This is my plan B. If there is a more idiomatic way, I'd be happy to learn it.

Comment: Apart from the obvious thing, that tests with inconsistent output are to be avoided, this is (pardon the expression) kind of a weird request. I mean, what if the test never fails (which should be the aim anyway)? Endless loop?

Comment: What might be worth doing is repeating it for a fixed 1000 times or so.

Comment: You're right @leun4m, but it can be interrupted once needed. Anyway, I am trying to reproduce the problem, and perhaps I have to switch to plan B.

Comment: Ah yeah, as long as it's just for bug tracking that should be alright :) You could wrap the test in a `loop` block. Provided the assertion is inside the block, this will stop the loop on fail and will run forever otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

*Before anyone copies this, please note: **this is code for bug hunting** and not a general suggestion to write tests!*

---

You can use `loop` to create endless loops (read the [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.loop.html)) that will only stop on panic, break etc.

This way you can run your test via `cargo test` and it will only stop on assertion fail or manually via interrupt (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>).

### Example

```rust
use rand::Rng;

#[test]
fn loop_inconsistent_test() {
    loop {
        inconsistent_test();
    }
}

fn inconsistent_test() {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let num = rng.gen_range(0..1_000_000);
    assert_eq!(num, 0); // if this fails, loop will stop
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I already know this turnaround. Unfortunately, it doesn't answer my question: "Is there any `cargo test` parameter".

Comment: not that I know of, thus this workaround...